# lowest level language until asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, programming-languages, assembly

it's assembler right? can someone please point out the progression that we've had in programming languages since assembler to the days of asp.net, namely the chronological order of languages?

Comment: What? How about this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_programming_languages

Comment: Assembler is still used, and in some places is still the king.

Comment: I love the fact that asp.net is seemingly the apex of all languages.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history

Comment: @John Nolan: I know, right? INTERCAL is much better!

Comment: The INTERCAL manual is unsurpassed in what it does best.  However, for actual use, lolcode is more practical.

Comment: Mondrian (http://www.sci.ccny.cuny.edu/~brinkman/software/mondrian/) is the future!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a [wiki timeline of all programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_programming_languages).

I would include a FTA table, but the list is **very** robust and extensive.

And also, the lowest language you ever get to is assembly (aside from straight up issuing machine instructions), regardless of what other language is built on top (including ASP.NET).  Other languages are really just abstractions on top of assembly.  In fact, ASP.NET gets compiled into IL (Intermediate Language) code, which then get's JITed into assembly.  Assembly is as close to the metal as you're going to get.

Comment: Don't forget entering machine language directly by using switches on the computer console.

Comment: Don't forget butterflies. Although, they may actually be extremely high level.

Comment: I never bought one of those computers, but I looked at the ads and thought about buying one.  The IMSAI at least had broad switches, and looked like it would be much easier on the fingers than the Altair.  Of course, the ENIAC was programmed with plugboards.

Comment: @John Yeah I was thinking someone might point that out, but I figured if someone wanted to actually issue machine instructions they are at a whole different level than this question. =P

Comment: Assembler is NOT the lowest level language you can reach.  While it isn't common, it is possible to generate application code that includes both C code and some kind of hardware description langauge (VHDL, Verilog, ...).    There's nothing *conceptually* wrong with generating (CMOS) transistor circuits or even chip geometry directly. Each of these have descriptive formalisms, and can be encoded and processed by tools.  I happen to to work on one tool,
DMS (www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) that has been used to manipulate C, C++, VHDL, Verilog, and transistor circuits.

Answer (score 5):

To be pedantic, "assembler" is not actually a language (any more than "compiler" is;-) -- rather, it's a program that takes a source file in "assembly language" and emits binary machine code. The binary machine code can be said to be lower-level than the assembly language, since the latter allows use of some symbols and often includes a macro processing ability as well.

"Below" binary machine code, there *may* be other levels, known as "microcode" (but there might not be -- the CPU *might* be implemented entirely in real hardware, without any microprogramming aspect). That might be relevant only if the system's architecture allowed programmers to alter the microcode, especially by adding to it, etc -- there have been machines that did that, but I don't believe any currently commercialized CPU does. So you probably don't have to care about that (and the by-now-esoteric distinctions between vertical and horizontal microcode, etc, etc;-).

Answer (score 2):

Programming languages are just ways to assemble solutions to computing problems.
The argument is "assembled out of what?"
From that point of view, I'd suggest the following evolutionary curve:

```
Napier's Bones
Babbage's difference engine
Jacquard (card) looms
(Conceptual) Abstract Turing machines/Post Systems/Church's calculus
Relay Computers (Aiken?)
Vacuum tubes as switching elements (Eniac)
Transistor-based computers
Microprogrammed machines
Integrated Circuits
Large Scale Circuits
```

with "assembler" being the programming language used to 
put together solutions consisting of instructions for
real machines starting with the vacuum tube systems.
(I'm not sure the relay machines actually had assemblers).
Programming langauges are just ways to put together high
level commands that reduce in effect to assembler instructions.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different dimensions to consider here, what I'd call vertical growth (languages build up over time from one generation to the next) and horizontal growth (syntactic improvements and reduction in complexity.)

A good explanation of vertical change is seen here: http://web.sxu.edu/rogers/sys/generations.html
And a nice, yet incomplete, illustration of horizontal change it here: http://oreilly.com/news/graphics/prog_lang_poster.pdf